# How to Run Python without a Terminal

Tags: python

I want to teach some students basic Python programming without having to teach them how to use the terminal.  Recently, I was teaching a 2 hour intro session, and not only did teaching terminal stuff take a long time, but it also intimidated a lot of the students.  I would like a solution where students wouldn't have to leave graphical user interfaces that they were comfortable with.

I also want the solution to let them execute a particular Python file (eg, not just using the interactive Python interpreter) and see the output from printing things.

Thanks!

Comment: Double-clicking on a `.py` file in Windows should work, although it will open it in a terminal window. Otherwise, I'd try a lightweight "IDE" like IDLE.

Comment: Another option would be to use some online interpreter (you can copypaste file contents in there). Then they don't even need to install anything to play with things. There are plenty around (mostly they support only very basic libraries though), i.e. http://www.skulpt.org/ http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surely that's what IDLE is for? It's not much good as an IDE, but it does work well for exactly what you describe - opening modules and executing them, and running commands in an interactive shell.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

https://www.wakari.io/

All in the browser.

Bonus points, you introduce them to IPython as well.

Take a look at the gallery too, https://www.wakari.io/gallery

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this: http://repl.it/languages/python

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like this:
http://learn.adafruit.com/webide/overview

Answer (score 0):

When I'm not near my own PC, I use ideone.com. I like that it is a universal IDE, which for me means both C++ and Python.